# Multiple level nuget dependency c#

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget

We're facing dificulties trying to make nuget install dependencies of dependencies. We publish custom nugets to an Azure Artifacts with more than one level of dependencies and nuget only installs the first level of these depencencies. As an example:

- Nuget **A** has a dependency on Nuget **B**.
- Nuget **B** has a dependency on Nuget **C**.

**A**, **B** and **C** are all nugets published in our azure artifacts.

Under this scenario, when we install nuget **A** in a solution it also installs nuget **B** (listed as a dependency), but nuget C is not installed (although it is necessary for **B** to work). Is there a way to accomplish this dependency hierarchy when installing a nuget?

All these nugets were published throughout a pipeline like this one:

```
parameters:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  nugetFeed: '[Our_GUID_Feed]'
  solution: ''
  project: ''
  BuildConfiguration: ''


jobs:
  - job: Job
    pool:
      vmImage: '${{ parameters.vmImage }}'
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Restore packages'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '${{ parameters.solution }}'
        vstsFeed: '${{ parameters.nugetFeed }}'
      env:
          System_AccessToken: $(System.AccessToken)

        
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Dotnet Build Project'
      inputs:
        arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.BuildConfiguration }} /p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber) /p:Optimize=false --no-restore' 
        projects: '${{ parameters.project }}'
        versioningScheme: byBuildNumber

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Dotnet Package Project' 
      inputs: 
        command: pack
        packagesToPack: '${{ parameters.project }}'
        buildProperties: Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2 
      displayName: 'Dotnet Push Project' 
      inputs: 
        command: push 
        nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
        publishVstsFeed: '${{ parameters.nugetFeed }}'
```

Edit:
Further info of the problem with an actual example:

This is the csproj of nuget **C**:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="9.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[Dependencies of C shown in vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avgvk.png)

This is the csproj of the nuget B:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NugetC" Version="1.0.20" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.10" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths-&gt;WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

[Dependencies of B shown in vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhCzC.png)

This is the csproj of nuget A:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.78" />
    <PackageReference Include="NugetB" Version="1.0.20" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.15.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NEST" Version="7.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths-&gt;WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

[Dependencies of A shown in vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPs5V.png)

As you can see in this last screenshot, C is not listed as a dependency of A when i try to install it.

Comment: This would normally just happen by default. How are you determining whether or not a package is installed? What exactly do you mean by "listed as a dependency"? Do you mean in Visual Studio? Are these NuGet packages public so we can look at them ourselves?

Comment: Yes, i mean in visual studio 2019, the "Dependencies" section when you select a nuget to install. I'm afraid the nugets are private. In case i didn't explain myself properly, when i said "nuget A has a dependency on nuget B" i mean it has this nuget installed, also for the B and C case.

Comment: One NuGet package *can* have a dependency on another, but doesn't "have a NuGet installed". I would stop talking about installation and just talk about dependencies - it'll be clearer. In this case, I would expect VS2019 to show C as a dependency of B, not as a direct dependency of A. So you should effectively be able to browse down the tree of dependencies to get from A to C, but you shouldn't see C as a direct dependency of A, because it's not.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusing use of "installed". But that's exactly the point, i'm trying to avoid having to manually add the C package when i add A. The only solution i see in this case is adding a dependency of C to A because in the end, i do need those for A to work. But it just seems redundant :(

Comment: You haven't explained *why* you think you need it to be a direct dependency though. When you restore project A, it *will* make sure that B and C are both available - at least if you're using .NET Core "SDK style" projects. We still don't have any information about what actual *problem* you're facing.

Comment: The problem is in the scenario i explained, when i try to install my nuget package A in a test library for example, to make some unit tests, the only dependency installed is B, when it actually needs also C because C is a dependency needed for B to work, hence A also needs C to work. when i install the package A, C is not recognised as a dependency. When I try to run my test it  throws an exception saying the C assembly could not be found.

Comment: Please give details of that project then (in the question, not in comments)... because normally I'd expect that to work fine, certainly for any SDK-style projects.

Comment: Kind of an obvious question... Are you sure the packages were created with the dependency correctly specified in the nuspec file?  Can you post the nuspec files?